# What does [None]* means in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype, iterable-unpacking

I was recently studying someone's code and a portion of code given below

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, height=0, elem=None):
    self.elem = elem
    self.next = [None] * height
```

What does it mean by `[None] * height` in the above code

I know what does `*` operator (as multiplication and unpacking) and `None` means in python but this is somehow different.

Comment: This simply generates a list which all the elements are None and the length of the list is height, when height equals to 0, it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do -

```
[element] * 3
```

You get -

```
[element, element, element]
```

That's what the code does, `[None] * height`

That is, if -

```
height = 4
[None] * height 
# equals [None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: so you mean that `self.next` is just a list of None?

Comment: When it is initialised, yes. If height is passed to be more than 0, you will get a list with number of elements, all None equal to the magnitude of height

Answer (score 3):

It means a list of `None`s with a `height` number of elements. e.g., for `height = 3`, it is this list:

```
[None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [None]  * 5
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Gives you a list of size `height` in your case